# Android BindAdapter with custom attribute with custom values (similar to visible attribute)

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

I've successfully made my first bind adapter and I wish to know a bit more about it.

I want to know how to make an attribute that can get only specific strings for a different state for my view.
For example every view has the visibility attribute that it can be"gone", "visible", "invisible"

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/loading_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/inventory_items_recycler"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/inventory_items_recycler"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/inventory_items_recycler"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/inventory_items_recycler"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:item_id="@{ItemID.BLACK_GLOVES.ordinal()}"
            />
```

I've made a custom attribute called item_id that get a number that represent enum value. And in my binding utils I have this code:

```
@BindingAdapter("item_id")
    public static void setItemName(TextView tv, int itemId) {
        tv.setText(ItemData.get(ItemID.values()[itemId]).getName());
    }
```

I prefer to have something similar to the visibility attribute that it value can be either "visible", "invisible" or "gone"

Bonus::
I wish android studio can auto-complete me for the possibilities that I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass directly the enum to your binding adapter, instead of converting it first to an int and than back to enum.

```
@BindingAdapter("item_id")
public static void setItemName(TextView tv, ItemID itemId) {
    ..
}
```

Then you could pass directly the enum in your xml:

```
app:item_id="@{ItemID.BLACK_GLOVES}"
```

This way you'll have a limited number of possibilities to enter and will be less likely to accidentally enter a meaningless integer.

However, binding adapters and custom attibutes are different. With a binding adapter, you still need to use the syntax of binding expression, ie: "@{  }".

`android:visibility` , on the other hand, is an attribute. You can also define custom attributes for your custom views and get something similar (have a limited number of input options and IDE shows you your options etc). But you shouldn't confuse that with binding adapters. These are two different concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@BindingAdapter("isGone")
    @JvmStatic
    fun View.setVisibility(isGone: Boolean) {
        if (isGone) this.visibility = View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
    }
```

Inside your xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_class"
            style="@style/TextStyleNormal.White"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_large"
            isGone="@{isSharedDailyActivity}"// it take boolean value
            app:buttonTint="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:useMaterialThemeColors="true" />
```